# lstlisting: numbering of longlines automatic broken by breaklines=true

Tags: listings, line-numbering, linenumber

I try to get linenumbers on longlines that breaklines=true break up:

So i added to my head the counter defintion:
`\newcounter{lstbreaklinesnumber}[lstnumber] % breaklines-counter`
so it should reset on each line count of listings

To print the line number of broken long lines I added to my lststyle:
`postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\arabic{lstbreaklinesnumber} \stepcounter{lstbreaklinesnumber}},`

Minimal-Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4, %
           draft=false,
           ngerman]{scrreprt}
        % Paket für Code / Listings
        \usepackage{listings}
        \newcounter{lstbreaklinesnumber}[lstnumber] % breaklines-counter
        \lstdefinestyle{gattranscript}{
          numberstyle=\small,
          basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
          breakatwhitespace=true,
          breaklines=true,
          breakindent=10pt,
          postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\arabic{lstbreaklinesnumber} \stepcounter{lstbreaklinesnumber}},
          captionpos=b,
          keepspaces=true,
          numbers=left,
          numbersep=5pt,
          showspaces=false,
          showstringspaces=false,
          showtabs=false,
        }
        \lstset{style=gattranscript}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Transkripte}
\section{Interview}
Beschreibung

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,escapechar=@]
  I: Heute mal ins Manual mit aufnehmen müssen. #00:09:46#
  B: Kündigen macht vieles leichter. Um. Kann ich, kann ich jetzt. #00:09:57#
  I: Ich meine dann, du hast gesagt, du machst das insgesamt drei Jahre. Ja. Das heißt, hier hat es sich sozusagen lassen. Wie ist es für dich einfach vom Anfang an gewesen? Wie war es am Anfang und wie ist es jetzt? Gibt's da? Kannst du da? Hast du irgendeine Erinnerung dran, die du vergleichen kann? Preisvergleiche sind böse und so? #00:10:26#
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output of the example document:
[image: The Output of the minimal example]

The expected output would be
a 1 after the break on line 2
and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the long broken line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: it would be much easier to debug your problem if you provided an example document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the suggestion. I edited my question and there is now an minimal working document. Can you now point me to a solution? :-)

Comment: if you look in listings.sty you see for example `\global\advance\c@lstnumber\lst@advancelstnum`  so the counter `lstnumber` is being incremented directly with the `\advance` primitive, not `\stepcounter`  so it does not trigger re-set of latex-specified sub-counters